# Sleuth Kit Autopsy won't run

Tags: command-line, software

I am trying to install Autopsy on my macbook but I cannot get the application running. I followed the instructions from [this site](http://macappstore.org/autopsy/):

> 1. Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.
> 2. Run in Terminal app:
>
>    ```
>    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
>    ```
>
>    and press enter/return key. Wait for the command to finish.
> 3. Run:
>
>    ```
>    brew install autopsy
>    ```

How do I open the application and get it up and running for Mac?

Comment: What happens when you try to run it? What logs/errors does it generate? We can't look over your shoulder and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue; there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to actually run the software. Just type "autopsy" into the terminal.